# Why are my Grid items not stacking on top of each other when using Media Queries?

Tags: css, media-queries, css-grid, grid-layout

I'm trying to get my grid items which are only 2 divs to stack on top of each other using media queries but no matter what I change nothing changes. I figured changing my 3 columns to 1 column would work for my media query...but still nothing. Let me know what I'm doing wrong because no matter what I try nothing changes.

HTML

```
<div class="showcase-grid">
        <div class="showcase-content">
          <h1 class="showcase-heading">
            My name is Edward Kelley and I strive to make the web 
awesome.
          </h1>
          <p class="showcase-text">
            I help businesses get noticed with fresh and innovative 
content.
            <br />Need something different for your business? Let's 
get in
            touch!
          </p>
          <button class="showcase-btn-1">About me</button>
          <button class="showcase-btn-2">Contact</button>
        </div>
        <div class="showcase-background-img">
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/847402/pexels- 
   photo-847402.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
```

SCSS

```
.showcase-grid {
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
display: grid;
align-items: center;

.showcase-content {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;

  .showcase-heading {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: 600;
  }

  .showcase-text {
    padding-top: 2rem;
    color: #828282;
  }

  .showcase-btn-1 {
    border: 2px solid #4f6df5;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    background-color: white;
    color: #4f6df5;
    padding: 1rem 1.5625rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 170px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    font-weight: 600;
  }

  .showcase-btn-1:hover {
    background-color: #4f6df5;
    color: white;
  }

  .showcase-btn-2 {
    color: white;
    background-color: #4f6df5;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    border: solid 2px #4f6df5;
    padding: 1rem 1.5625rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 170px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
  }

  .showcase-btn-2:hover {
    color: #4f6df5;
    border: 2px solid #4f6df5;
    background-color: white;
  }
}

.showcase-background-img {
  grid-column: 4;

  img {
    width: 420px;
  }
}
}


@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .showcase-grid {
grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are *explicitly* setting your `grid-column`. Change `grid-column: 1/3` to `grid-column: span 2` and do away with `grid-column: 4` - see demo below:

```css
.showcase-grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
}

.showcase-grid .showcase-content {
  grid-column: span 2; /* CHANGED */
}

.showcase-grid .showcase-content .showcase-heading {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.showcase-grid .showcase-content .showcase-text {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  color: #828282;
}

.showcase-grid .showcase-content .showcase-btn-1 {
  border: 2px solid #4f6df5;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  background-color: white;
  color: #4f6df5;
  padding: 1rem 1.5625rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 170px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.showcase-grid .showcase-content .showcase-btn-1:hover {
  background-color: #4f6df5;
  color: white;
}

.showcase-grid .showcase-content .showcase-btn-2 {
  color: white;
  background-color: #4f6df5;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  border: solid 2px #4f6df5;
  padding: 1rem 1.5625rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 170px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.showcase-grid .showcase-content .showcase-btn-2:hover {
  color: #4f6df5;
  border: 2px solid #4f6df5;
  background-color: white;
}

/*.showcase-grid .showcase-background-img {
  grid-column: 4;
}*/

.showcase-grid .showcase-background-img img {
  width: 420px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .showcase-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="showcase-grid">
  <div class="showcase-content">
    <h1 class="showcase-heading">
      My name is Edward Kelley and I strive to make the web awesome.
    </h1>
    <p class="showcase-text">
      I help businesses get noticed with fresh and innovative content.
      <br />Need something different for your business? Let's get in touch!
    </p>
    <button class="showcase-btn-1">About me</button>
    <button class="showcase-btn-2">Contact</button>
  </div>
  <div class="showcase-background-img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this was just what I needed. Would you recommend me use the span instead of strictly declaring what columns and or rows to hold the positions of my grid items?

Comment: you can use both as per the context, here you wanted a the column of the image to *change* - so strictly specifying column would not be helpful in this case :)